# approximation of $\pi$ obtained from the series of $\arcsin \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

An approximated value for $\pi$ can be obtained from the series of $\arcsin \frac{1}{2}$.
We know that:

$$\arcsin x =  \sum_{k=0}^n    \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!! (2k+1)} \cdot x^{2k+1} + R_{2n+2}(x;0) = x+ \frac{1}{6} \cdot x^3+ \frac{3}{40} \cdot x^5 + ...+ \frac{(2n)!}{4^n \cdot (n^2)! \cdot (2n+1)} \cdot x^{2n+1} +R_{2n+2}(x;0)$$
choosing $0$ as the central point for the series.

According to the integral form of the remainder:
$$R_{n}(x;x_0)= \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \int_{x_0}^{x} (x-t)^n \cdot f^{n+1}(t)\, dt  $$ and considering that we are looking for $R_{2n+2}(x;0)$ with  $x_0=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$ R_{2n+2}(\frac{1}{2};0) = \frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}   \cdot     \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} t^{2n+2} \cdot  
[1-\eta(t)^2  ]^{-n-\frac{3}{2}} \, dt    $$
in which $0<\eta(t) \le t < \frac{1}{2}$.

I can't understand this last passage.

Can someone try to explain it simply?

Comment: What is $\eta(t)$ here? It is not defined in your question.

Comment: yes, indeed I wrote it in the post

Comment: Can you tell us where does this comes from?

Comment: in my book it is not specified and I'm wondering if there is something that I don't know

Comment: The problem is that the statement is fuzzy. It should at least be: prove that it exists $t \mapsto \eta(t)$ such that... Also the fact that $\eta$ doesn't depend on $n$ looks strange to me.

Comment: perhaps I'm ignoring something but I can assure that this is what it is written in the book